# How can I match a user id value from a form input to records in my database?

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

Hi I'm trying to match a user id value from an input on a form to records in my database.  I'm trying to show a column (itemname) of data in a dropdown select menu that match a userid value from a forms input.  I don't know if I'm properly defining my variables or what im doing wrong but cant see what I'm missing.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
<?php

// Create the connection to the database
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");


// Check if the connection failed
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  die();
}



  if (isset($_POST['userid']))
{
    $userid= $_POST['userid'];

   $query = "SELECT itemname
        FROM seguin_orders
  WHERE username = '".($userid)."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
}
?>
```

**FORM WITH DROPDOWN**

```
<form action="xxx" method="post" name="form1">


<select name="xxx"><option value="">-- Select One --</option>


 <?php 

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
         echo '<option value =" ' . $row['itemname'] . ' ">' . $row['itemname'] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>

</select>


<input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" />

</br>

<input id="userid" name="userid" type="text" value="demo@gmail.com" readonly="readonly"/>



<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>


</form>
```

Comment: `$query = "SELECT itemname
        FROM seguin_orders
  WHERE username = '".($userid)."'";`

Comment: I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: Try adding a semicolon after WHERE username = '".($userid)."'

Comment: Put `}` before closing php tags in first example. You oppened if statemend, but not closing it

Comment: you don't need a `;` after `}` in while loop.

Comment: closed if statement removed ; after while loop and added semicolon after after WHERE username = '".($userid)."'     ...page loads fine no errors...but not showing column data as selections under drop down

Comment: i dont get how else i could write it out to work

Comment: @SteveBrown just a note, when you working with any IDE or code editor, you have highlighting. Watch for colors. For example `$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);` in your code is red, so this mean that this is part of `$query` as a string. This indicate me that there is no ending point for `$query` variable.

Comment: what do i need to add an ending point

Comment: After `$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);` `put var_dump($result); die();` and tell us what you get. If there is nothing to show, or not what you expect, it's probably something with query (like misspell or something)

Comment: edit to '`WHERE username = '".($userid)."'";` to complete the string.

Comment: Just to clear something, user needs to submit user id in form in order to show the dropdown?

Comment: Yes, I suppose. Because after clicking on submit, I am getting the values in the `select` drop down.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var_dump' (T_STRING)

Comment: @PrerakSola thats the point of my question. Because he has check for `$_POST`, so that means the dropdown is visible after user submits user id. There is no way to show dropdown first time after user load the page.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Aleksandar.
what do you want exactly steve?

Comment: so what you suggest i should do to get my drop down to show selections

Comment: well i want column values related to the userid value to show as selections under my dropdown

Comment: You will need to use ajax for this. Refer his link: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: @SteveBrown in order to show dropdown first time user load the page, you need different approach. First, user id needs to be set before querying database. So, checking if `$_POST` is set is not good here. Two solutions: 1) Login in user and showing dropdown using his/her user id (hard), 2) AJAX. Create input field to enter user id and submit form without refreshing page and append results to dropdown (medium to solve)

Comment: @Aleksandar.....2nd method seems easy enough...i can create the input field and submit without page refresh..just the appending results to drop down not sure how I would write that one out...if u could just help me with that plz...all this info u have helped me with has done a great deal for me understanding it...n i thank u for that...ive gotten farther with u alone here in under half and hojur than i have over the last 2 weeks thanks so much 4 ur help

Comment: @SteveBrown when you submit user id,php return results from db. Just return it like `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
         echo '<option value =" ' . $row['itemname'] . ' ">' . $row['itemname'] . '</option>';
        }` and append it with ajax to dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**==SOLUTION FOR AJAX FORM==**

**orders.php**

```
<?php

// Create the connection to the database
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");


// Check if the connection failed
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  die();
}



  if (isset($_GET['userid']))
{
    $userid= $_GET['userid'];

   $query = "SELECT itemname
        FROM seguin_orders
  WHERE username = '".($userid)."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
         echo '<option value =" ' . $row['itemname'] . ' ">' . $row['itemname'] . '</option>';
        }
}
?>
```

**original page with form**

*This is just basic and simple, for you to understand. You can change it and make more secure. Please, read comments to understand*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#">
    <div class="pre-dropdown">  <!-- This class is here to hide this mini form after submit with jquery -->
        <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid">
        <button id="submitId">Submit Id</button>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">  <!-- This is hidden because there is no data, but when userid is submited, this will be visible -->
        <select name="xxx" id="dropdown-select">
            <option value="">-- Select One --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
     $(function(){

        $('.dropdown').hide();  // Hide dropdown div when page is loaded, mbetter way will be with css, but it's enough for now


        $('#submitId').on('click', function(e){  // Things to do when 'Submit Id' button is clicked
            var userid = $('#userid').val(); // Grab user id from text field
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submit, we are submiting form down with ajax.

             $.ajax({
              url: "orders.php",
              data: {
                userid: userid
              }
            }).done(function(data) {
                $('.pre-dropdown').hide();  // Hide mini form for user id
               $('.dropdown').show(); // show dropdown
              $('#dropdown-select').append(data); // append results from orders.php to select
            });
        });
     });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Change form the way you need. I am hidding `pre-dropdown` because if user submits `userid` again, we will append results twice.

Comment: SUPER JOB of explaining it and breaking it down...your freakin awesome! Thank you so much for your help and time.  I had to change   WHERE username = '".($userid)."'";  -to-   WHERE userid = '".($userid)."'";   ....to get it work but most importantly it works perfectly!  I hope and wish you all the luck...you have truly made a difference for me.  I spent so long trying to understand this and no one could get what I wanted I didn't know how to explain it...but you got it were able to help me thanks so much!!!  I know everyone who sees this post will gain much knowledge from you...THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You did two mistakes

You miss  end of if condition ending }, and remove semicolon ; from while loop also string ending is missing.

In short you  need a good IDE that can let tell you basic error in your code

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing echo of your code to something like this-->

```
echo "<option value =\"". $row['itemname'] ."\">". $row['itemname'] . "</option>";
```

or try using mysqli_fetch_array() rather than mysqli_fetch_assoc()

And More Over change your sql query to something like this

```
$query = "SELECT itemname FROM seguin_orders WHERE username = '$userid'";
```